# Can't make progress bar visible after button click

Tags: java, android

I want to show simple round progress bar after I clicked on a button, but it's doesn't work. Look on my XML

```
            <FrameLayout
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                 android:visibility="visible"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                 android:layout_gravity="center"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:id="@+id/progress_layout">

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </FrameLayout>
```

And my java code

```
postPet = (Button) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.post_pet);
    postPet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
     });
```

There is no error, nothing happening after click.

P.S. I initialize variable progressBar in fragment's onCreate method

```
    LayoutInflater infl = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup rootGroup = (ViewGroup) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
    View root = infl.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_pet_form, rootGroup);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) root.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing progressBar.show(); ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your pb over a button in xml like:

```
  <FrameLayout
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:id="@+id/progress_layout">
<Button
android:id="@+id/post_pet"
your button description here />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

this way it has to work and you would not need to inflate the pb additionally.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding one of the associated styles: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

You can also set the background color of its parent to some value, and see if any part is opaque: if not, the progress bar has no width and height or is not visible.

Finally you can use hierarchyviewer with the emulator to inspect the layout and verify what's happening.

Also if the frame layout has no other children, get rid of it and use layout_gravity to position the progress bar in its parent: no need for the extra viewgroup!